Amazon Bedrock Prompt Management Variants is not working
I tried to create a prompt with two variants. I could not get it working, even when I mentioned two variants, it only created the first one and completely ignored the other. The sample of the program is here
https://github.com/rajib76/aws_bedrock_examples/blob/main/examples/prompt_management/create_a_prompt_with_variants.py

it looks like the variants are getting created, but does not show up in the console
